# Correct way to enumerate ideas in English

Tags: grammar, punctuation, semicolons, colons

My mother tongue is Spanish and in Spanish the correct way to enumerate ideas is saying something like the following:

I have many ideas, among them we can find: idea A; idea B; idea C ;and finally, idea D.

With this in mind I would like to know how is this done in English and if the following paragraph needs to be modified.

> Among her multiple duties and responsibilities, the following activities, for one of the main natural products that the company was developing, stand out: supply chain (from supplier to end customer) study and design, including the entire production process; time schedule planning, demand and capacity calculation; and finally, personnel, material, informative and financial flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of a colon, semicolons, and commas is perfectly acceptable.

From the [University of Leicester](https://www2.le.ac.uk/offices/ld/resources/writing/grammar/grammar-guides/semicolon):

> Use the semi-colon to separate items in a list when one or more items contain a comma.
>
> The speakers were: Dr Sally Meadows, Biology; Dr Fred Eliot, Animal Welfare; Ms Gerri Taylor, Sociology; and Prof. Julie Briggs, Chemistry.
>
> The four venues will be: Middleton Hall, Manchester; Highton House, Liverpool; Marsden Hall, Leeds; and the Ashton Centre, Sheffield.
>
> The main points in favour of the system were that it would save time for buying, accounts and on-site staff;  it would be welcome by the reception staff; it would use fewer resources; and it would be compatible with earlier systems.

This disambiguation of phrases with commas is one of the main uses of semicolons.

---

Even when list items don't contain commas, semicolons can still be used if the items are lengthy.

Per [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/punctuation-in-lists):

> If each item in the list is quite long, semicolons can be used instead of commas:
>
> This criticism can be interpreted in various ways: as an attack on Shakespeare’s presumption in challenging the university-educated dramatist; as an accusation of plagiarism; and as an attack on Shakespeare’s plagiarism of Greene.